# Possible Link Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146719/accessing-values-using-subscripts-without-using-sub2ind) post.  When editing, the link appears properly in the preview.  However, the question shows something like:

> (i.e. using
>   http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS%5Fen-USUS294US304&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sub2ind">sub2ind).
>   E.g.

Why would they be different?

Answer (score 6):

your link is

```
http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?
/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html&
http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-USUS294US304&aq=f&
sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sub2ind
```

That's never going to work very well (embedded http://, etc). I recommend simplifying it to...

```
http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?
/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html
```

edit: we now auto-encode any additional colons after the protocol part of the URL