# Links with URLS containing http:// more than once

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible Link Bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6808/possible-link-bug)

Sometimes I use the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/) to link to really good websites that no longer exist. The URLs are of the form `http://web.archive.org/web/〈date|*〉/〈url〉`, e.g., `http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/https://superuser.com/index.html`. The links display properly in the preview window, but display garbled in the posted answer.

See for example:

[Cygwin: Assembly language development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561273/cygwin-assembly-language-development/579987#579987)

https://superuser.com/questions/11082/what-are-some-of-the-most-useful-outlook-plugins/11190#11190

Comment: This is a duplicate, I'll try to find the original.

Comment: You should edit your question. You've got "The links display" on the same line as a URL. I bet you want a blank line there.

Comment: Here it is, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6808/possible-link-bug/6810#6810 . This is a known issue, but doesn't appear to be too high priority.

Answer (score 1):

[http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http://superuser.com/index.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http%3A//superuser.com/index.html)
http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http%3A//superuser.com/index.html

```
[su]: http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http%3A//superuser.com/index.html
[http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http://superuser.com/index.html][su]
[http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http%3A//superuser.com/index.html][su]
```

Resulting in:

```
<div class="post-text"><p>
<!--                                                                                                                                           v -->
<a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http%3A//superuser.com/index.html" rel="nofollow">http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/<a href="http://superuser.com/index.html" rel="nofollow">http://superuser.com/index.html</a></a> 
<a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http%3A//superuser.com/index.html" rel="nofollow">http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http%3A//superuser.com/index.html</a></p> 

<pre> 
[su]: http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http%3A//superuser.com/index.html
[http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http://superuser.com/index.html][su]
[http://web.archive.org/web/20030606214502/http%3A//superuser.com/index.html][su]
</pre> 
</div>
```