# Internationalized domain name silently dropped

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

If you try to enter a internationalized domain name as your "website" in your profile, it will be silently stripped of any non-English characters.

Ex: My webiste is [http://linus.unnebäck.se/](http://linus.unneb%C3%A4ck.se/) but when I try to enter that it saves it as `http://linus.unnebck.se/` when it actually should display `linus.unnebäck.se` and link to `http://linus.xn--unnebck-9wa.se/` (or just link with the ä, don't now what is the right thing to do).

As I wrote this post I also noticed that the markup ends the link at the first non-English character aswell, look at the example above.

Comment: With `markup` I mean the form where you write your posts, or actually the backend which converts the things I type to (x)html.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When John Smithers edited [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns/37357#37357), I noticed that it works if you escape the unicode character. So http://linus.unnebäck.se actually works. The markdown source for this is `http://linus.unneb&#228;ck.se`. It's still just a workaround, but better than those `xn--bla-xyz` things.

Since SO takes a whitelisting approach to characters in links, I suspect there won't be a change anytime soon; especially since Jeff is notorious for talking about "crazy moon language" for umlauts et al. But I agree it would be nice.

---

**Epilogue**: Seven weeks after I wrote this, Jeff hired me – and it only took me a little over five years to make good on the "it would be nice" thing. And umlauts and ASCII characters lived together in harmony and [happily ever after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/non-ascii-characters-in-external-links/259980#259980).

Comment: Jeff is a bit too anglo-centric for my liking sometimes. After all, he's running an international community. On the other hand, IDNs arguably add a layer of horrible chaos to what used to be a half-way straightforward system. I think we would have been better off without them.

Comment: "Jeff is a bit too anglo-centric for my liking sometimes" - I18n is an incredibly complex thing to get right, especially for the first few releases of a project, even more so if you've never done it before. Some projects have a person just dedicated to I18n! I don't think it's fair to blame Jeff for this. (P.S. Germans are also anglo, as in anglo-saxon)

Comment: I don't understand your crazy moon languages!! But then, I barely understand English, or as we like to call it, "American".

Comment: Surprised to see that this actually works in my profile. Wouldn't that allow for url-obfuscation of some kind?

Comment: We detected an invalid link in your post, please correct it. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)

Comment: working on fix for the invalid detection

Comment: It'd be nice if this were fixed for Japanese.SE.  [A user wanted to link to 国語文法.com and had no idea how.](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/24344/revisions)  I was able to work around it for now by escaping, but...

Comment: Awesome epilogue! Thanks for taking the time and adding it :)

Comment: @Pekka: Re *"Jeff is a bit too anglo-centric for my liking sometimes"*: Has the state of affairs improved since then?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum hmmmmmm https://mobile.twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1291842963090206720  

Answer (score 3):

As balpha notes, there is a workaround -- use the encoded version of the crazy moon language characters:

`http://linus.unneb&#228;ck.se`

This is fairly standard for oddball URL characters since we have a strict whitelist.