# Auto-Link-validator marks punycode URLs as invalid

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, link-validator

So the new-find-and-comment-on-invalid-links script has kicked into action. And the way it works is pretty nifty, especially the auto-delete-on-fix. However, it seems to mark answers containing URL-encoded [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) as invalid links. Example: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/links-using-internationalized-country-code-top-level-domain-arent-properly-disp/121271#comment366578_121271) comment

Comment: wow punycode, this is the first time I heard of it

Comment: @waffles [It's a thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).

Comment: I sorted this out, it is awaiting a deploy (probably not today)

Comment: @waffles [status-completed] perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aha, this was completed a while back, it was a result of url normalization.