# Profile website does not support unicode

Tags: bug, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internationalized domain name silently dropped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41644/internationalized-domain-name-silently-dropped)

So, I registered a new domain today that contains some unicode with TLD that supports IDN.

But, my poor Server Fault profile just strips the unicode out of the About Me "website" field :(

`яѱ` just looks so much nicer than the punycode equivalent of `xn--41a2e`

Comment: When you register a domain name like this, do you actually expect that the average user will be able to figure out how to type it into their browser's address bar?

Comment: @TheEstablishment - not at all. But that's not the point :) What is the point is that there are now even unicode TLDs, and people who use them *will* know how to type them in. E.g. `‏السعودية` is a **valid** TLD

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Custom keyboards exist.. I've seen users typo-ing umlauts/etc in chat.

Comment: I find it amusing that keyboards with umlauts (or any non-ASCII characters, in fact) are considered "custom". For many, many people those are the only keyboards they see in their day-to-day lives.

Comment: Wasn't arguing this shouldn't be fixed, just asking a question. 'Tis what comments are for. And no, of course there are people with keyboards that have these keys. They're just more rare than the people who *don't* have them. And just because you have letters with umlauts on your keyboard doesn't mean you have a full complement of Cyrillic or Greek characters or whatever else.

Comment: does URL-encoding it using the poste editor help? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121271/133693

Comment: @Sathya - sadly, no, it comes out as `http://%D1%8F%D1%B1.com` (I have left my MSO profile in this state if you want to have a look)