# Allow IDN URL in profile

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, jobs

I wanted to update my profile at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ with my URL (davidhaberthür.ch) which is perfectly valid, but Stack Overflow complains that "Web site Url does not appear to be valid". I now used the workaround URL which contains an 'ue' for the 'ü', but would like to use my real name URL in my profile.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for pointing this out. Would you try it again?

Comment: Works for me now

Comment: Doesn't for me: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/171811/habi No matter how many 'ü's I put in the URL, they're always swallowed…  **Update:** It works for careers.stackoverflow.com though

Comment: @Habi In case you're still interested in using an IDN URL in your regular stack exchange profiles, try the hack described in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41647/227127).

Comment: Thanks James, that worked as intended.