# Can't post link to website with URL address containing unicode characters

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-ASCII characters in external links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/non-ascii-characters-in-external-links)

Consider the following URL: [http://www.erfolg-für-alle.de](http://www.erfolg-f%C3%BCr-alle.de) (posted to SO short time ago)

Apart of the automatic URL detection breaking on the "ü" letter, even if I explicitly try to make this a link of [some other text](http://www.erfolg-f%C3%BCr-alle.de), it's simply not working ignoring the link completely.

The link appears in the source as `[1]: http://www.erfolg-für-alle.de` and the "linked" text is also fine: `[some other text][1]` however, no link and no shoes.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Well I learned something today: Never knew that unicode characters could be in domain names

Comment: @TheLQ yeah, found out about it not long ago too following Hebrew address - the address itself get changed to `http://www.xn--erfolg-fr-alle-nsb.de/` and IE show alert, but in both IE and Chrome it does work properly. :)

Comment: @TheLG: `http://☃.net`

Comment: This is no duplicate - in the "original" there's no solution for this problem at all.

Comment: @maa that's because it's not a bug.. currently SO does not support such links and I accept it.

Comment: That's fine.... but by closing this question the solution gets lost and the original question provides none. I know, you've solved you problem already, but I think that either the this question shouldn't go away or the old question should be extended. Closing a non-duplicate based on 2 matching words is wrong, no matter how many people agree with it.

Comment: @maa for what it's worth I wouldn't close this question but I also don't think it's worth fighting to re-open it.. anyway nothing is lost, there's link to the "original" question with the answers that convinced me.