# The hyperlink button doesn't work when the URL contains encoded characters

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-ASCII characters in external links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/non-ascii-characters-in-external-links)

I tried using the *URL shortcut* in the bar to enter a URL, http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/ingles/index.php?lingua=portugues-ingles&palavra=ol%E1, but it didn't work. Why?

See here and try yourself putting this link on the word Test.

To input the URL, I put `http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/ingles/index.php?lingua=portugues-ingles&palavra=` in the shortcut, and manually edited the URL to include `ol%E1`.

Comment: Works if you enter the UTF8 encoding of á (%C3%A1) instead of the Latin1 encoding. Chrome console log has an "Uncaught URIError: URI malformed" error when you use the Latin1 thing.

Comment: Wait, now I'm not sure I noticed the same bug.

Comment: @Mat the truth is the link don't works on the site. Take a look and try these links
`http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/ingles/index.php?lingua=portugues-ingles&palavra=ol%E1` (ok) , `http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/ingles/index.php?lingua=portugues-ingles&palavra=olá` (bad), `http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/ingles/index.php?lingua=portugues-ingles&palavra=ol%C3%A1` (bad).