# On Meta, have Community ignore posts with a [status-*] tag when bumping

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, community-user

Just ran across [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6808/possible-link-bug), which was bumped by [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/highlander) for having been unanswered. However, it was answered by Jeff (no upvotes), along with a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag. I gave an upvote so that it wouldn't be bumped again. But, Community should ignore those posts, since they have an official answer.

Possible exceptions, as pointed out by random, are the statuses `planned` and `deferred`.

Statuses `bydesign`, `completed` and `declined` should be ignored by Community.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Community♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) really should know to leave well enough alone some times.

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) or [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) might be interesting to float up to the front now and then until they get switched over to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: And maybe not bump closed questions so we can close and not see things like this get bumped: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37262/why-cant-i-access-stackoverflow as it did just now. I can see stirring old questions/requests/etc. so they don't get lost in the shuffle.

Comment: This question was marked as [status-denied]. Does that mean Community will bump questions marked [status-completed] or [status-denied]?

Answer (score 15):

completed stuff should have at least one answer with an upvote, so we know our "completion" wasn't total B.S. that everyone hates.

Answer (score 5):

Considering the pace at which questions land off the first page on meta (really slow), having something that's irrelevant only adds noise. They really should not be bumped back up if they've been completed, I completely agree.

Comment: (somebody spotted this as a dup, so I merged your answer into this older question)

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1 for being my first @name notification ;-p

Answer (score 4):

I actually think we should go even further here on Meta and completely disable automatic bumping by the Community user. Bumping was supposed to get some additional attention to questions in the hopes of getting additional answers, but I don't think that it makes sense on a discussion site.

Comment: Not for the community, but the devs probably should see when a bug report is updated (i.e. with better repro steps).

Comment: Well when a real person edits the post to improve it, that should definitely bump it. I was talking about the automatic bumping back to the top of the front page by the Community user.

Comment: Since we don't allow duplicate discussion questions, I think it's important to have those old discussions bumped every now and then.

Comment: I was thinking about this and I like it, but I would add an exception for feature requests.  I think posts tagged `feature-request` with no `status-*` tag should get bumped from time to time, to encourage voting on them.

Comment: I think that bumping some questions doesn't make sense, for example the ones tagged [meta-tag:faq]. If one of those questions don't have an up-voted answer, they would be bumped all the time from the Community user, and voting an answer for those questions doesn't normally make sense (if it's not for sorting the answers).