# Stack Overflow logo on maintenance page has the wrong aspect ratio

Tags: bug, status-completed, maintenance

The Stack Overflow logo on the maintenance page is squashed!—
[image: example of correct and incorrect aspect ratios]

> EDIT:
>   This issue was [raised again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56763/stack-overflow-logo-on-maintenance-page-has-the-wrong-aspect-ratio) on July 12, 2010.

Comment: confirmed -- the image is 250x61, but the `img` tag gives it 250x70

Comment: And that would be the good part about going offline. You get to test your offline pages for errors!

Comment: Also the error page on meta asks me to report the error on meta. I then entered an endless loop and almost stackoverflowed (no pun intended)

Comment: Way to focus on the important stuff ;-p

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Just imagine the server hadn't overheated -- this might have gone unnoticed for ages!

Comment: This is not fixed as of today..

Comment: @blorg it is fixed. There are two sets of "offline" pages, one comes from HAProxy, the other comes from ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest waiting for http://meta.stackoverflow.com to come back up, and then report it here.

Comment: To those who are downmodding me, why?  Is this a bad answer?

Comment: ... because this question was 5 months old and was marked as complete 4 months ago

Comment: But it's still showing up as an unanswered question in the listing.  So I provided an answer.

Comment: Sorry, Chris -- it was the right idea... The "unanswered" list isn't too useful here on meta. I never engage in pity upvoting but I think one is legitimately warranted here, so please take this +10. It's our fault for having a weird "unanswered" situation on meta.

Comment: The recursion and dependency hell in this answer requires an upvote.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/on-meta-have-community-ignore-status-tags-when-bumping

Comment: The irony is that a few days ago another user dropped an answer onto this question with the explicit intent of getting this off the unanswered list. 10K+ users can see it as deleted. :) So Chris, don't worry, you're not the only one who gave it a good try.