# Stack Overflow Error Site

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow logo on maintenance page has the wrong aspect ratio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38620/stack-overflow-logo-on-maintenance-page-has-the-wrong-aspect-ratio)

i think there's a little bug on the "error / downtime" site of stackoverflow, isnt it?
[image: stackimage]

the logo of "stackoverflow" is streched a little bit, because the "html" says it has a height of 70 but in real its only 61 high.

just wanted to let the developers know that little "bug"

Comment: so much for [status-completed]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38620/stack-overflow-logo-on-maintenance-page-has-the-wrong-aspect-ratio

Comment: You must mean StackOverflow.

Comment: No, choise is clearly talking about SO's evil twin, Stack Overlow.

Comment: @choise: Is your "f" key broken? :-)

Comment: @balpha it was fixed in source control -- I think this file exists only for HAProxy so it is a duplicate.