# Stack Overflow logo on maintenance page has the wrong aspect ratio

Tags: bug, status-completed, logo, maintenance, offline

Here's the issue:

[image: oh noes]

The `<img>` in question has a `height` property of 70, when the actual image's height is 61.

---

**Note:**
This is a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38620/stack-overflow-logo-on-maintenance-page-has-the-wrong-aspect-ratio) which is marked `status-complete`.

However, the issue is still there (or is back again). Since I can't remove the `status-complete` tag, I went with a repost. Meta-meta: was there a better way?

Comment: If you had edit privileges, I would've recommended bumping it. With less, I think it's acceptable to post an answer on that question to bump it. But it is definitely important to bring it up again, so perhaps whatever tools satisfy the need...

Comment: Bringing it up again was probably ok.

Comment: FYI, I edited the original question to include a link to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is coming from HAProxy, not us, so Geoff has to fix it.

Comment: Ah, the venerable `[status-someone-else's-problem]`.

Comment: @Popular `[Status-deferred]` already exists.

Comment: @devin, no, that's `[status-touching-my-nose]`.