# Data dump readmes aren't up to date

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-dump

This is a small one: The new field `EmailHash` in the `users` table of the March data dump hasn't made it into the `readme.txt` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question has received [status-completed], I'm putting an answer so the question won't get bumped by [this obnoxious guy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Comment: ...or someone could fix the code so that red tags make a post ineligible for bumping.

Comment: @Ether: Yep, but there's no official word on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/on-meta-have-community-ignore-status-tags-when-bumping