# No Community ♦ bumping in Meta please?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, community-user

There's quite some discussion about Community ♦ bumping. It's purpose is to get a question more attention/responses/answers.

I think that on Meta it's extremely rare for a posted question not to get any attention/repies/answers. I see Community ♦ only bumping up old, already talked to death, no longer relevant, or no one cares anymore kind of topics. Perhaps I don't spend enough time on Meta, but I've yet to see a good bump.

Should Community ♦ bumping be halted for Meta.StackOverflow?

**Related** : Disabling this feature was also mentioned in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/on-meta-have-community-ignore-status-tags-when-bumping/11671#11671).

Comment: I should have know better than to ask this on Friday.

Comment: I mentioned this [a while back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/on-meta-have-community-ignore-status-tags-when-bumping/11671#11671) but I'm glad it has its own `feature-request`.

Comment: Related: [Turn off Community bumping for meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9143/10968) at Physics.SE

Answer (score 9):

Yes. New users to meta should be searching in the tags they are interested in to read up on older discussions. I was reading the archives for at least a month before I posted my first question and started following new posts.

It's clear that the "rules" don't work the same way on meta, so this would be one more way of acknowledging it. E.g. it often doesn't make any sense to accept an answer, upvoting and downvoting mean different things, and discussions and subjective questions are totally normal and encouraged.

Plus, this would never be tolerated on Stack Overflow:

[image: Robocop returns!]

Comment: Yes, I like it. I said yes. :)

Comment: 1+ for the awsome picture.

Answer (score 5):

I think it bumps those questions that are eligible for the "unanswered" list -- i.e., no upvoted answers. That's why I sometime just add an answer to such a question or vote up an answer if there's one, so it won't get bumped again.

Comment: @balpha- I thought it bumped questions with no upvoted answers.

Comment: @rlb That's precisely what he said. Questions with no upvoted answers are those eligible for the "unanswered" list.

Comment: Thanks @ccornet, I found it now. Google's "did you mean" wasn't of much help at first.

Comment: @balpha - then, adding an answer doesn't take it off of Community's eligible bump list - you have to pray that a kind soul upvotes your answer to that dusty question.

Comment: @rlb.usa: Well, yeah, but either it makes sense to post a (real) answer, in which case it will likely get an upvote, or you can just have the answer contain "answered to stop bumping" or some sort of in joke that'll probably get you an upvote. Either way, you'd just want to do this when the answer is on the front page anyway because it *has* been bumped, so there's no harm.

Comment: @balpha - But the problem still exists - minus one question, and it will happen again. Wash, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are many new users coming in to Meta all the time, so it gives them a chance to give input on old issues, without creating new questions.

Comment: @Lance_Roberts  I think the chances of the user finding a bumped question interesting are same as finding an interesting question through the other more normal means.

Comment: And, I dont mean to sound overly pessimistic, but in all honesty, a reply/comment on an old Meta question usually goes unnoticed (and therefore is useless).