# Does Community ♦ really need to bump questions here on Meta?

Tags: feature-request, meta, community-user, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No Community ♦ bumping in Meta please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48441/no-community-bumping-in-meta-please)

I realize the code is just inherent in the system, and I generally like it for new users, but can we turn that off on Meta since there's not really anybody here who cares about posts that are 2 years old and already resolved ...

I mean, we care about them, they exist, but do they need to float back to the top for Community's wildly deviant purposes?

Comment: @Charles: Ironically, it probably wasn't even bumped by community to be noticed.

Comment: "Community's wildly deviant purposes" I think you have your answer there