# Don't have the community bump Questions that are marked [Status-Completed] or [Status-By-Design]

Tags: feature-request, community-user, bump

There are many times where a feature is requested, or bug reported and then fixed, but no answers are posted to the question.

In this case, the community user will bump this Question even if it is no longer relevant.  See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52189/) example.  There is no reason for the community to bump this question, even though it had no answers.

Comment: Sorta subsumed in the body of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/on-meta-have-community-ignore-status-tags-when-bumping

Comment: Your link is a deleted question from the purge, by the way.

Comment: @Grace, yeah I just saw that. I don't have a good current example though.