# status-completed and status-bydesign posts should not show up in the unanswered list

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, meta, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove questions with moderator tags from the Unanswered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65429/remove-questions-with-moderator-tags-from-the-unanswered-list)

I was going through the unanswered question list and saw that a lot of them are tagged as either [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). There are no answers for such questions (generally most of these are bug fix or new feature requests).

So my suggestion is to remove such questions from the unanswered list, since they are as good as answered in a way. There is no action required from other users for such questions. They can either be closed with comment of "status-completed" or "status-bydesign." Or, if there is a better way to remove these questions from the unanswered list, it would be good, I feel personally.

Comment: Slightly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52418/2598

Comment: I imagine more people would prefer that [status-bydesign] questions didn't show up on the Unanswered list not mechanically but by actually getting answered...