# -1 for closing, why not +1 for reopen?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A question gets an automatic -1 vote when it is closed.

Why isn't that -1 vote removed when a question is reopened?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert the Community downvote on a closed question when it gets reopened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91211/revert-the-community-downvote-on-a-closed-question-when-it-gets-reopened)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is incorrect; certain types of "egregious" aka "the OP should have known better" close reasons (Not a Real Question and Off Topic) are automatically downvoted by Community at the time of close.

This vote is not undone, because a question extracts effort from the community when it is closed. We want to actively discourage questions that require notable effort to "fix".

Comment: [Should questions closed as "not a real question" and "off topic" get an automatic downvote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84978) is a bit unclear about the idea's status. Maybe add and accept an answer explaining what exactly was implemented?

Comment: @eat looks like that question is correct to me, so no

Comment: No, I mean the question I linked to. Why not add an answer saying `certain types of "egregiously incorrect" close reasons (Not a Real Question and Off Topic) are now automatically downvoted by Community at the time of close.`? See the comments above for an example of user confusion

Comment: I completely agree with what Pekka is saying here. If I look at [this answer of yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/on-meta-have-community-ignore-status-tags-when-bumping/60022#60022), then I read from it that you also think it should be visible from the answers to a feature-request _how_ it was implemented. (ping, @Eat)