# Bug in automatic downvote for closed NARQ and off-topic questions

Tags: bug, closed-questions

Questions that are closed as "not a real question" or as "off-topic" are supposed to receive an [automatic downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati). However, for months now I've noticed that this doesn't always seem to work. Sometimes the question will receive the automatic -1, but other times it won't. And I haven't been able to figure out a pattern as to why sometimes it happens and other times it doesn't.

In the last few hours I closed two questions, one as [NARQ](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/45344/i-am-going-to-launch-product-beta-version-next-month-whats-my-next-steps) and one as [off-topic](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/45347/can-i-sue-a-foriegner), and neither of them got the -1. I noticed that when the page refreshes just after the close vote the -1 appears, but it disappears as soon as I click away to another page. Just to be sure I double clicked on the vote count and both display as 0/0.

Is this a bug?

Here are two older examples: [one](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/45239/want-a-good-best-practices-for-lead-follow-up-management-flow-chart-for-my-inspi) and [two](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/39154/kpi-monitoring-alerting-management).

**Update:** Based on [Jarrod's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161116), the bug appears to be related to the declining of a flag. However, I just closed [this question](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/46648/whats-a-typical-salary-for-senior-java-developer-in-riyadh-saudi-arabia) as off-topic, and the automatic downvote never took. I noticed the question didn't get the automatic downvote, even before I handled the "Please explain the nature of this closed post" flag. Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: I've also noticed that the downvote is temporary. In other words, after a few days, the automatic downvote is removed.

Comment: @jmort253 not relevant here, both questions Zuly linked to are only few hours old.

Comment: @Zuly - What I'm about to do is _for science_, you might feel a little pinch.

Comment: Ok, closed this as OT. The down vote 'stuck' as expected, and was removed as expected when I reopened. And, here's a band-aid. Can't reproduce on Meta.

Comment: @jmort253 Are you sure about that? I don't think it's temporary at all unless the post is reopened, when it's reversed just like the closure

Comment: @TinyTimPost Two comments. 1) Re: "can't repro on Meta", I've noticed that sometimes the downvote will stick and other times it won't. So I think more science experiments are needed on MSO to confirm.

Comment: 2) Are you sure about the downvote being reversed after reopening the question? I searched on Meta before posting this question, because I wanted to run my own science tests, but what I found was that the downvote is not reversed. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91211) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104190/1-for-closing-why-not-1-for-reopen). Also, take a look at my rep history, there are several +5 and one -2 for this question, but no +2 to reverse the downvote. I don't have enough rep to check the actual vote count on this question. Can someone check that?

Comment: @BenBrocka Are you sure the downvote is reversed after reopening? See my comment above to Tim. I seem to remember that sometimes it does reverse and other times it doesn't. Kinda like what I'm seeing with the automatic downvote sometimes not sticking after a question is closed.

Comment: I think this is one for the devs to test in their sandbox. Trying several other scenarios would result in way too much fun .. err, I mean noise on Meta.

Comment: @TinyTimPost I agree. That's why I chose not to run my own science experiments :-) Can you check the vote count on this question for me? Does it still show the -1?

Comment: I'm 95% sure they're removed. The -1 is no longer on this question for example. You may be seeing other people's downvotes being added/removed

Comment: @BenBrocka I haven't found any evidence on MSO to support that. That said, I know from experience that the automatic -1 is _sometimes_ reversed after a question is reopened. I don't think it happens all the time though. WRT this question, it's strange. My rep history displays +23 = (5 * +5) - 2. There is no +2 to reverse the -2. I'm pretty sure the -2 was from Tim's closure, because it matches the time (plus who would downvote such an awesome question :-) ) However, I know how much rep I had before I posted this question, and I can confirm that it's really +25 and not +23.

Comment: @Zuly: the down-vote was removed (and the -2 with it), but your reputation history hadn't picked this up yet. It should look right now...

Comment: @BenBrocka - No, there have been closed posts that I've come back to on PMSE where the automatic downvote was reversed.  There were 0 votes in many cases, so I knew it wasn't because someone upvoted... :(

Answer (score 8):

After looking at the code, it's a bit more complicated.

The intent of the code was to remove community-cast downvotes that were given to a question when it was flagged as offensive or spam, **when a moderator declines those flags.**

However, **any** downvotes by community are deleted when a moderator **declines** flags, regardless of which flag type is being declined and **regardless of what context those downvotes were given**.  When flags are deemed helpful, the downvotes stay.

This feels like a bug - downvotes that were given along with close votes (i.e. when closing as NARQ or off-topic) should remain when flags are handled.  The only downvotes to be removed are those given during spam/offensive flagging and only when those flags are declined.

Comment: Hi Jarrod, we hardly *ever* decline flags on PMSE, simply because we don't want people to stop flagging. By default, I mark everything as helpful, and I've seen the downvotes disappear even if I mark as helpful the automated message: "Hey you, yes you with the diamond, leave a comment!".  With that said, I haven't closed anything as NARQ in a few months, so this information is based on how I remember things working...

Comment: Also, I want to add that I think the close vote downvotes should be removed *if a post is reopened.*

Comment: @jmort253: Spam flags should be treated with strictness... If the flagged post doesn't meet the definition of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(electronic), the spam flag should be declined.  Also, is that an obscure Pink Floyd, The Wall reference? :)

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. Is there a fix planned for this? I agree that it should work exactly as you state in your last paragraph - spam/offensive flag downvotes should be removed if the flag is declined and NARQ/off-topic close downvotes should remain regardless of flags.

Comment: FYI - I just closed [this question](http://answers.onstartups.com/q/3598) as off-topic and cleared the "please leave a comment" flag as helpful (which I never do) and the downvote stuck. So this looks to be correct.

Comment: Jarrod, @jmort253 brings up the issue of how to handle these automatic downvotes if a question is reopened. I think there is some confusion as to how this is supposed to work, because the information presented on MSO seems to contradict what happens in practice, _at least sometimes_. I think there might be a bug in the logic that handles the reopening of a question, possibly related to this bug. I asked a [question here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160898), but have not received a satisfactory answer. Can you shed some light on that?