# URLs in URLs parsed incorrectly in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

It looks like an [older bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6808/possible-link-bug) has [resurfaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077010/why-do-we-use-printf-function-in-c/4077063#4077063):

> Though I disagree with the premise that printf is faster, worth noting that programming-designs.com/2009/02/…" rel="nofollow">"Of the 136 pages we tested on the site over the past 90 days, 17 page(s) resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed without user consent.".

Generated from:

> Though I disagree with the premise that printf is faster, worth noting that ["Of the 136 pages we tested on the site over the past 90 days, 17 page(s) resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed without user consent."](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://programming-designs.com/2009/02/c-speed-test-part-2-printf-vs-cout/&client=googlechrome&hl=en-US).

Answer (score 1):

Looks okay now (it's probably how SoftwareElves noticed [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69879/comment-nofollow-exploit), which was fixed), so marking this is status-completed.