# Link 'properly' set in the edit mode but incorrect in the final answer

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

I have posted recently a link (among others). I set it, as always, with `[]()`. The bug happens is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12657189/938236) to an old question.

The JavaScript preview looks properly.

[image: Edit preview seems right]

The parsed code looks this broken.

[image: finish version is broken]

Well, that's the bug. I think both JavaScript/whatever method SO uses and PHP/whatever should have the same rules for formatting. If it's intended to be like that, here's a proper bug. Maybe it has something to do with [this older bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69215/urls-in-urls-parsed-incorrectly-in-comments). Also, I checked it's not for the "" writing instead '' but it didn't work.

Comment: The URL should be encoded as it contains quotes, and spaces. It is the  preview that is wrong.